# What is a creature that could serve as a subtitute for a Baluchitherium?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league

We are looking for a creature that could serve as an Adventurers League substitute for a colossal [Baluchitherium](https://www.blacksharkenterprises.com/single-post/2016/02/10/The-Island-of-Lost-5e-Monsters-The-Baluchitherium-and-The-Dragonne) (i.e. 100’ tall at the shoulder instead of 20’ and with hit points closer to a dragon) - which is no longer in 5e Dungeons and Dragons.

As more background - Adventurers League(AL) allows for game conventions to submit modules for review to be declared "AL Legal" for widespread use. A variety of [guidelines](http://dndadventurersleague.org/how-do-i-ccc-and-other-questions/) must be met for acceptance. One regards monsters:

> **What monsters can I put in my adventure?** You can choose from creatures
>   in sources published under the Dungeons & Dragons brand such as the
>   Monster Manual or Volo’s Guide to Monsters. You can modify them in
>   small ways, such changing a bandit to an elf bandit using the rules
>   Dungeon Masters Guide, or saying the party faces a large animated
>   statue, but using the statistics of an ogre reskinned as that statue.
>   You may not invent new monsters. The stat blocks in the adventure’s
>   appendix must be faithful reproductions of the creature as found in
>   its original product. Minor adjustments should be called out in a
>   sidebar.

What could be a suitable AL creature that could be skinned to be a Baluchitherium but 100’ tall instead of 20’ and with proportionally more hit points?

Comment: Note that changing the hit points might be considered inventing by AL, as if it is significant it would require a CR adjustment.

Comment: Are you converting an old published module to 5e for AL play?  Or are you creating your own module?

Comment: What challenge rating is your adventure running at?

Answer (score 4):

I looked through the MM and VGtM and I really couldn't find any suitable large creatures except for the various dinosaurs (all else seemed to be monstrosities or demons and such).  I imagine that AL would probably require you to keep them as dinosaurs, which means that needs to make sense for your adventure.  Good luck finding a substitute, but imagine that producing adventures for AL must be difficult.